# While trying to create file system on my partition getting an error

Tags: centos7, rhel7

Iam operating centos 7 on a virtual machine 
I have  /dev/sdb of size 1G

I used the following command to create a extended partition

fdisk  /dev/sdb

n -- for adding new partition

e -- extended

Partition number --1

First sector --  default

Last sector -- +512M

entered W

partprobe  /dev/sdb

mkfs.ext4  /dev/sdb1  /mnt

Got this error

Mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-dec-2013)
Mkfs.ext4 : invalid blocks '/mnt' on device '/dev/sdb1'

Not able to figure it out 
I created a directory /data and tried it in place of /mnt still not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to `man mkfs.ext4` you need to either ignore last parameter given (/mnt) becasue the last argument AFTER the device is fs-size, not some path
OR provide actual fs-size, like `512m`

Comment: Silly me got mixed up with mount I guess thanks janmyszkier will look up man as well for  variety of options